# Store output of cv::imencode into sqlite3

Tags: c++, opencv, sqlite, blob, imread

I'm trying to store an image (`.png`) into a `sqlite3` database. A simple grayscale image will be creating by `opencv` and will be storing into a buffer by using of `cv::imencode(cv::Mat img, params)` command (the output of function is a `std::vector<uchar>`).

Next I'd like push this into a database. Therefore I'm preparing a `sqlite3` table, statement and so on... this works well.
To adding a `blob` content I'm doing following steps (minimal example):

```
bool MyClass::bindTableContent(int index, std::vector<uchar> data){

 char * blob_imdecode = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data());

 this->rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(this->statement, index, blob_imdecode, sizeof(blob_imdecode[0]) * data.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);
 if (this->rc != SQLITE_OK) {
  return false;
 }

 if(sqlite3_step(this->statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
  return true;
 }
 else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

After doing this, the `blob` data is namely stored in a database, but as wrong data type (I guess something goes wrong, perhaps the length is wrong, ... ).
If I do `imdecode` of this vector and save that by using `imwrite` then the image will be saving correctly.

Nevertheless, if I read the image with `fstream` and do the same as above, the data will store correctly (as `.png`) into a database (minimal example):

```
bool MyClass::bindTableContent(int index, std::string image_path){

 char * blob;
 std::ifstream::pos_type size;
 std::ifstream file(image_path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
 if (file.is_open()) {
  size = file.tellg();
  blob = new char[size];
  file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
  file.read(blob, size);
  file.close();
 }

 else{
  blob = NULL;
 }

 this->rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(this->statement, index, blob, size, SQLITE_STATIC);

 delete [] blob;
 if (this->rc != SQLITE_OK) {
  return false;
 }

 if(sqlite3_step(this->statement) == SQLITE_DONE){
  return true;
 }
 else{
  return false;
 }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
I would be very grateful for any help :)

*** Solution *** 
If someone has the same issue, here is the solution:

Make a hard copy of the inputed vector data / replace:

```
char * blob_imdecode = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data());
```

to

```
char * blob;
blob = new char[data.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
 blob[i] = data[i];
}
```

Comment: if you managed to solve the issue yourself you should post the solution as an answer instead of edit to the question

Comment: I have never understood why anyone would want to put an image in a database where you can't see it, or edit it without writing SQL and where it bloats your database and makes backups bigger. Do you have a moment to explain the rationale please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell You can store in an image some data of your process or something else what you don't want to see. The content of the image (values of each pixels) is important only for the behind processes.